# How are Uniform Layout Qualifiers in GLSL spaced out

Tags: opengl, glsl

So for attributes the spacing between indexes is vec4, so if I had 2 matrix as an attribute, they'd be **layout (location = 0) in mat4 a** and **layout (location = 4) in mat4 b**

If I did the same for 2 uniform matix, what would the index of matrix b be?

Side note: with OpenGL 4, are VBOs also attributes, there isn't a key word for vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Uniform locations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Location) don't work like attribute locations.

Every [basic type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Basic_Type_(GLSL)) in OpenGL takes up 1 uniform location. So a `float` and a `mat4` both take up 1 location. The only time multiple locations are consumed is if you're using an aggregate (aka: struct or array) of basic types. Each basic type element of the aggregate, recursively, takes up one location.